# How to trace conflicts in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

I have a web page where the footer is showing on top of the page only in IE9: http://goo.gl/XnSNJ

There is no JavaScript error, so I am not sure what it can be. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to debug or fix this?

Comment: Hi Basem, could you please share a portion of the relevant CSS?

Comment: post your HTML . may be incorrect HTML ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is a very strict browser.  It is unforgiving in terms of bad HTML/CSS/JS.

With that said, the rendered HTML is atrocious.

In IE, the style for #footwrap3 is not being applied.

I would start by looking through the HTML for unclosed HTML elements.  This is also the reason why the floating footer is not appearing in the same place.